# easy counting set

Tags: combinatorics

Let n be integer.Given the first 2n numbers.In how many ways we can arrange them so the sum of 2 adjasent numbers is odd number.Solution?:For the first postion we have 2n choices,second n,third n-1,fourth n-1 as we continue (n-1) and the result is 
2n.n.$((n-1)!)^2$?

Comment: Yes, you're thinking is correct, I looked at it slightly different, although it should be $(n-1)^2$ at the very end.

Comment: Which allows you to simplify to $2n\times n\times(n-1)!^2$

Comment: Yes,thanks anyway I was just doing this ,had a typo at the end n-1

Answer (score 1):

you have $n$ odd numbers and $n$ even, if you want the property in the problem all the even numbers need to be in even positions or all even numbers need to be in odd positions (because they have to be odd-even-odd-even....  or even-odd-even odd.... )There are two choices.

Once this has been established you need to order the even and the odd numbers. There are $n!$ ways to do it for the even numbers and $n!$ ways to do it for the odd numbers.

The answer is hence $2\times n!^2$